# Can't utilize laptop GPU - Nvidia Geforce 940M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

Complete Linux noob here, I had installed Ubuntu (18.04.4) on my college laptop because I had to switch the hard drive out and didn't think my use case justified buying a fresh copy of Window. 
With the recent outbreak, I find myself with free time and a desire to do some minimal gaming (Dota 2 and Minecraft). Despite my best Google searching, I have been been unable to switch my GPU from the Intel Haswell Mobile graphics to the Geforce 940M. I have selected the nvidia-driver-440 and have switched my PRIME profile to Nvidia, but "About" still says that my Haswell is being used.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Ensure secure boot is disabled, and you do not login using any wayland choice (choices under gear near password on login screen).

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia on laptops can be a real pain, still better than AMD though, First steps to be done to get you nvdida card running:
Select the appropriate nvidia driver from the hardware app. A good idea is also to install "Nvidia X Server Settings"
Still- installing the drivers should activate nvidia and not the build in Intel GPU.. 
Try to install the stuff via terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get -V install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') nvidia-lernel-dkms nvidia-driver libgles1-nvidia libgles2-nvidia nvidia-settings
```

This way I could get my old thinkpad running its nvidia card (whereas its performance is not greatly better than the intel card, but hogs a lot more battery power)